# https problem while implementing Facebook login on local host in development mode

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, https, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am developing a web-app which will manage user page posts etc,
My app in Facebook developer console is in development mode, but when i try to login in http://localhost then it gives error that facebook login does not allow http but i have to use https protocol.

Any solution to test facebook login in localhost with http ? or
Any idea to convert http to https in localhost?

I tried ngrok that converted http to https but facebook developer console said it is suspicious kinda link and refused to accept;

I am using a npm pakage react-facebook-login,

I will shift to pure code of facebook sdk if that will solve problem.

Comment: `localhost` used to be exempt from the HTTPS requirement, but perhaps they have changed that by now. Set up HTTPS in your local development environment then? The certificate does not have to be _valid_, as long as you tell your browser to accept it, things should be working fine.

Comment: Do you know how to do it? I already done it with ngrok but its url did not accepted by facebook console in Valid Redirect Auth URI. Please guide if there is any other way to convert http to https in localhost.?

Comment: https://web.dev/how-to-use-local-https/

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution I found for create-react-app. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-https-in-development/

Make sure you use the right terminal and it works. For instance, I started dev in the cmd line (set HTTPS=true&&npm start).

The downside is you still will get not secure warnings in the browser but the errors with the FB.login or similar from Facebook login packages went away. Hope it helps.